# Error in plot_summs : argument is missing, with no default

Tags: plot, regression

I have written a multiple linear regression code. When running it, I have an error when creating the regression coefficient plots.

This is how my code looks like:

```
### Preparation####
rm(list = ls())
options(scipen=55)
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

#Load packages
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(CerioliOutlierDetection)
library(MASS)
library(car)
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)

#Set Working Directory
setwd("D:/Data/01_Data/Data_NRW/") 


#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Read data####
KPNRW <- readRDS(file="01_Main/NRW_Kaufpreise_einzeilig.rds")

#Rename variables 
KPNRW <- KPNRW %>% 
  rename(Price_total = Gesamtkaufpreis..Euro.) %>% 
  rename(Lot_Size_m2 = Gesamtgrundstücksfläche..qm.) %>% 
  mutate(Lot_Size_ha = Lot_Size_m2/10000) %>% 
  mutate(Price_m2 = Price_total/Lot_Size_m2) %>% 
  mutate(Price_ha = Price_total/Lot_Size_ha) %>% 
  mutate(Share_Haupt = Price_total/Lot_Size_m2) 


#Sales Year 
KPNRW$Year <- substring(KPNRW$Datum.Kaufvertrag, 1,4)
KPNRW$Quarter    <- quarters(as.Date(KPNRW$Datum.Kaufvertrag, format = "%y.%m.%d"))
KPNRW$Q3 <- ifelse(KPNRW$Quarter=="Q3",1,0)
KPNRW$YearQuarter <- paste0(KPNRW$Year, ".",substr(KPNRW$Quarter, 2,2))

#Deflation 
DeflatorQuarter <-read.csv2(file="./02_Deflator/Deflator_Quartely_BIP_All_20230202.csv")
KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, DeflatorQuarter[,2:5], by="YearQuarter")
rm(DeflatorQuarter)

#Deflated Prices 
KPNRW$Price_total_df <- (KPNRW$Price_total/KPNRW$BIP_X13JDKSB)*100
KPNRW$Price_ha_df    <- KPNRW$Price_total_df/KPNRW$Lot_Size_ha
KPNRW$Price_m2_df    <- KPNRW$Price_total_df/KPNRW$Lot_Size_m2

#Land-Types 
KPNRW$D_Gruen <- ifelse(KPNRW$Nutzungsart.Grdst..LuFw %in% c("GR"), 1, 0)
KPNRW$D_Acker <- ifelse(KPNRW$Nutzungsart.Grdst..LuFw %in% c("A"), 1, 0)

#Naturschutzzonen
KPNRW$D_NSG <- ifelse(KPNRW$Planungsrecht..überörtlich. %in% c("Naturschutzgebiet"), 1, 0)


#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Administrative ####
NRW.rbz <- read_sf(dsn="./03_Admins/02_Shape_Files", layer="dvg2rbz_nw")
NRW.krs <- read_sf(dsn="./03_Admins/02_Shape_Files", layer="dvg2krs_nw")
NRW.gem <- read_sf(dsn="./03_Admins/02_Shape_Files", layer="dvg2gem_nw_o")

#Landkreise
KPNRW$Gemeindekennzeichen <- paste0(0, KPNRW$Gemeindekennzeichen)
KPNRW$Landkreis <- paste0(substring(KPNRW$Gemeindekennzeichen, 1,5),"000")
KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, setNames(NRW.krs[,c("GN", "KN")], c("Landkreis.Name", "Landkreis","geometry")), by="Landkreis")
KPNRW <- st_as_sf(KPNRW)


#Number of plots
test <- KPNRW[!duplicated(KPNRW$Landkreis),]
plot(st_geometry(test))






#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Land Cover ####
Gmd_NRW <- read.csv2("./03_Admins/01_Land_Cover/GmD_Land_Nutzung_NRW_2016_2021.csv")
Krs_NRW <- read.csv2("./03_Admins/01_Land_Cover/Kreise_Land_Nutzung_NRW_2016_2021.csv")

colnames(Krs_NRW)[4:18] <-paste0(colnames(Krs_NRW)[4:18], "_Kreise")
colnames(Gmd_NRW)[4:18] <-paste0(colnames(Gmd_NRW)[4:18], "_Gmd")
Gmd_NRW$Gemeindekennzeichen <- paste0(0, Gmd_NRW$Gemeinde)
Krs_NRW$Landkreis <- paste0(0, Krs_NRW$Kreise, "000")

Gmd_NRW$X <- NULL
Gmd_NRW$Gemeinde <- NULL
Krs_NRW$X <- NULL
Krs_NRW$Kreise <- NULL


#Merge
# KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, Krs_NRW, by=c("Landkreis","Year"))
KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, Gmd_NRW, by=c("Gemeindekennzeichen","Year"))




#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Bodenrichtwertzonen ####
# https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/infrastruktur_bauen_wohnen/boris/BRW/
NRW.BRW                     <- read_sf(dsn="./03_Admins/03_BRW/BRW_EPSG25832_Shape", layer="BRW_2023_Polygon")
NRW.BRW$Ackerzahl.BRW       <- NRW.BRW$ACZA
NRW.BRW$Gruenlandzahl.BRW   <- NRW.BRW$GRZA
NRW.BRW$Gemeindekennzeichen <- NRW.BRW$GESL
NRW.BRW$Bodenrichwert.EURm2 <- NRW.BRW$BRW

#Simplification
NRW.BRW <- NRW.BRW[!rowSums(is.na(NRW.BRW[,c("Ackerzahl.BRW","Gruenlandzahl.BRW")]))>1,]
NRW.BRW <- NRW.BRW[NRW.BRW$NUTA %in% c("A","L","KUP","GR"),]
# NRW.BRW <- NRW.BRW[!duplicated(NRW.BRW$BRWZNR),]


# Da im KPNRW-Datensatz keine Information bezüglich der BRW-Zone ist,
# mergen der durschnittlichen Gründlandzahl auf Gemeindeebene 
NRW.BRW.G <- NRW.BRW[!is.na(NRW.BRW$Gruenlandzahl.BRW),]
NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW <- 0
NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW <- ifelse(nchar(NRW.BRW.G$Gruenlandzahl.BRW)==2,as.numeric(substr(NRW.BRW.G$Gruenlandzahl.BRW,1,2)), 0)
NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW <- ifelse(nchar(NRW.BRW.G$Gruenlandzahl.BRW)>2,mean(as.numeric(strsplit(NRW.BRW.G$Gruenlandzahl.BRW, "-")[[1]])), NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW ) #Mittelwert
NRW.BRW.G        <- NRW.BRW.G[!NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW==0,]                           
NRW.BRW.G$GZ.GMD <- ave(NRW.BRW.G$GZ.BRW, NRW.BRW.G$Gemeindekennzeichen, FUN=mean)
NRW.BRW.G$GZ.GMD <- round(NRW.BRW.G$GZ.GMD)
NRW.BRW.G <-NRW.BRW.G[!duplicated(NRW.BRW.G$Gemeindekennzeichen),]  


# Da im KPNRW-Datensatz keine Information bezüglich der BRW-Zone ist
# mergen der durschnittlichen Ackerzahl auf Gemeindeebene                    
NRW.BRW.A <- NRW.BRW[!is.na(NRW.BRW$Ackerzahl.BRW),]
NRW.BRW.A$AZ.BRW <- 0
NRW.BRW.A$AZ.BRW <- ifelse(nchar(NRW.BRW.A$Ackerzahl.BRW)==2,as.numeric(substr(NRW.BRW.A$Ackerzahl.BRW,1,2)), 0)
NRW.BRW.A$AZ.BRW <- ifelse(nchar(NRW.BRW.A$Ackerzahl.BRW)>2,mean(as.numeric(strsplit(NRW.BRW.A$Ackerzahl.BRW, "-")[[1]])), NRW.BRW.A$AZ.BRW) #Mittelwert
NRW.BRW.A        <- NRW.BRW.A[!NRW.BRW.A$Ackerzahl.BRW==0,]                           
NRW.BRW.A$AZ.GMD <- ave(NRW.BRW.A$AZ.BRW, NRW.BRW.A$Gemeindekennzeichen, FUN=mean)
NRW.BRW.A        <- NRW.BRW.A[!duplicated(NRW.BRW.A$Gemeindekennzeichen),]  
NRW.BRW.A$AZ.GMD <- round(NRW.BRW.A$AZ.GMD)


#Merge: Durchschnittliche Bonität auf Gemeindeebene  
KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, st_drop_geometry(NRW.BRW.A[,c("Gemeindekennzeichen","AZ.GMD")]), by=c("Gemeindekennzeichen"), all.x=T)
KPNRW <- merge(KPNRW, st_drop_geometry(NRW.BRW.G[,c("Gemeindekennzeichen","GZ.GMD")]), by=c("Gemeindekennzeichen"), all.x=T)

#Check number of NA
table(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität))

#Ackerzahl
KPNRW$Bonität <-ifelse(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität) & KPNRW$D_Acker==1, KPNRW$Ackerzahl.des.BRW, KPNRW$Bonität) #Info aus Datensatz
KPNRW$Bonität <-ifelse(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität) & KPNRW$D_Acker==1, KPNRW$AZ.GMD, KPNRW$Bonität)            #Info aus Merge

#Grünlandzahl
KPNRW$Bonität <-ifelse(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität) & KPNRW$D_Gruen==1, KPNRW$Grünlandzahl.des.BRW, KPNRW$Bonität) #Info aus Datensatz
KPNRW$Bonität <-ifelse(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität) & KPNRW$D_Gruen==1, KPNRW$GZ.GMD, KPNRW$Bonität)               #Info aus Merge

#plus 110 obsservations
table(is.na(KPNRW$Bonität))




#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Filter ####
KPNRW <- KPNRW %>% 
  filter(Lot_Size_m2 >= 2500) %>% 
  filter(Price_ha >= 500) %>% 
  filter((D_Gruen+D_Acker)>0) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Bonität))


#__________________________________________________________#
###• Outlier Detection####
# minimum covariance determinant estimator for outlier detectionRousseeuw and van Driessen 1999) 


# install.packages("CerioliOutlierDetection")
# install.packages("robustbase")
library(CerioliOutlierDetection)
library(robustbase)

#Variables: remove outlier which are not common for given variables. 
KPNRW$Trend    <- as.numeric(KPNRW$Year)-(min(as.numeric(KPNRW$Year))-1)
vars  <-c("Price_m2","Lot_Size_ha","Bonität","Trend")
p  <- length(vars) 

#Drop Geometry of the data set
KPNRW <- st_drop_geometry(KPNRW)


#Outlier detection for grass and arable land separately. 
MCD_output_Acker <- covMcd(KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Acker==1,vars],nsamp = 1500, seed = set.seed(2018), alpha = 0.75)
MCD_output_Gruen <- covMcd(KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Gruen==1,vars],nsamp = 1500, seed = set.seed(2018), alpha = 0.75)

cutoff_Acker <- hr05CriticalValue( hr05AdjustedDF( nrow(KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Acker==1,vars]), p, method = c("HR05")), p, 0.025)
cutoff_Gruen <- hr05CriticalValue( hr05AdjustedDF( nrow(KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Gruen==1,vars]), p, method = c("HR05")), p, 0.025)

outlier_Acker <- which(sqrt(MCD_output_Acker$mah) > cutoff_Acker)
outlier_Gruen <- which(sqrt(MCD_output_Gruen$mah) > cutoff_Gruen)

#99 Observations removed 
nrow(KPNRW)
KPNRW <- rbind(KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Acker==1,][-outlier_Acker,],
               KPNRW[KPNRW$D_Gruen==1,][-outlier_Gruen,])
nrow(KPNRW)

#__________________________________________________________#
###•  Descriptives ####

Variables <- c("Lot_Size_ha", "Bonität")   #Add more 


#### Data Set
KP_stat <-
  as.data.frame(t(apply(
    KPNRW[,Variables],
    2,
    FUN = function(x)
      c(Mean   = mean(x),
        Median = median(x),
        SD     = sd(x),
        # Q00    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 0)),
        Q01    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 0.01)),
        #Q25    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 0.25)),
        # Q75    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 0.75)),
        Q99    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 0.99)),
        #Q100    = unname(quantile(x, probs = 1))
      )
  )))


#
plot(density(KPNRW$Bonität), xlab="Bonität", main="Verteilung: Bodenqualität")




#__________________________________________________________#
###•  First regression ####
KPNRW$YearQuarter <- as.character(KPNRW$YearQuarter)

LM0 <- lm(log(Price_m2)~
           #Lot Characteristics
             Bonität
           + Lot_Size_ha
           + Anzahl_Flaechen
           + D_Gruen
           
           #Land-Cover
           + I(Share_LWD_Gmd*100)
           + I(Share_Settle_Gmd*100)
           + I(Share_Forest_Gmd*100)
           + D_NSG
           
           #Fixed effects
           + YearQuarter
           + Landkreis.Name, 
           data=KPNRW)

#Heteroskedasticity-consistent standard errors
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

Rob_LM0 <- coeftest(LM0, vcov=vcovHC(LM0, type="HC0"))
Rob_LM0

# See website for an example how to illustrate coeffiecients: 
# https://jtools.jacob-long.com/reference/plot_summs.html
# plot_summs 
library(jtools)

plot_summs(LM0, 
           omit.coefs = c(paste0("Landkreis.Name",unique(KPNRW$Landkreis.Name)),
                          paste0("YearQuarter", unique(KPNRW$YearQuarter)),
                          "(Intercept)"),
)
```

I get the following error warning when running the code:

```
Error in plot_summs(LM0, omit.coefs = c(paste("Landkreis.Name", unique(KPNRW$Landkreis.Name)), : argument is missing, with no default
```

I would like to create regression coefficient plots. Any thought?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).